# Non-existing service after the upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, uncaught-exception, contao

I upgraded my Contao website from 4.13.38 to 5.3.1. Everything was successful, Contao Manager is working okay, but the website is not functioning. The error is logged in var/logs and points to a non-existent service "**contao.image.image_sizes**":

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "contao.image.image_sizes". Did you mean one of these: "contao.image.imagine", "contao.image.imagine_svg", "contao.image.resizer", "contao.image.sizes"?" at Container.php line 263

{
"exception": 
"[object] (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException(code: 0): You have requested a non-existent service "contao.image.image_sizes". Did you mean one of these: "contao.image.imagine", "contao.image.imagine_svg", "contao.image.resizer", "contao.image.sizes"? at /opt/testportal/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:263)"
}
{
"request_uri": "https://testportal/contao/login",
"request_method": "GET"
}
```

Both FE and BE are not working.

What could be the problem here? I searched for solution in Internet, but although there were similar questions, I didn't find real solution.

Beside contao-core bundles, there are rocksolidthemes (madeyourday) plugins installed and upgraded.

Comment: The error means that the service `contao.image.image_sizes` isn't bound to any concrete implementation, and therefore it doesn't exist. You need to take a deeper look at the docs there because you've made a major upgrade and this service may had its name changed or maybe deprecated.

Comment: Did you check whether the service was renamed or removed in the later version of Contao?

Comment: I have only found this: "getImageSizes() public static method is
deprecated since Contao 4.1, to be removed in Contao 5. Use the contao.image.image_sizes service instead." But it seems somehow this new service is missing.

Comment: There is one line in vendor/contao/core-bundle/config/services.yaml where I found service named contao.image.sizes but there is no contao.image.image_sizes. At the moment, that attracts me the most attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating Contao you will also always need to update the theme, according to the theme vendor's instructions - especially when updating to new minor or major versions. In your case you did not update the RockSolid Custom Elements config files of the Oneo theme for example for the new Contao version which resulted in this error.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

The problem was caused by theme I used. The theme files should be also actualized after the upgrade, but since the BackEnd is not working, it's not possible to do that by theme import, and files should be replaced manually over FTP.

In my case, it was Oneo theme and files that were using the wrong service are:

```
rsce_oneo_centered_wrapper_start_config.php
rsce_oneo_feature_box_config.php
rsce_oneo_tab_nav_config.php
rsce_oneo_timeline_config.php
```

In each of these of files there is line

```
'options' => Contao\System::getContainer()->get('contao.image.image_sizes')->getAllOptions(),
```

and in actualized version (for Contao 5.0 - 5.3) the line is changed to:

```
'options' => Contao\System::getContainer()->get('contao.image.sizes')->getAllOptions(),
```

**Alternative solution:**

In folder config there should be added file **services.yaml** with following code:

```
services:
    contao.image.image_sizes:
        class: Contao\CoreBundle\Image\ImageSizes
        public: true
        arguments:
          - '@database_connection'
          - '@event_dispatcher'
          - '@contao.translation.translator
```

This is the same configuration as it is for service **contao.image.sizes** in core-bundle, but for some reason the system is searching for **contao.image.image_sizes**. Since that service is not exists, we copied the definition under the name of missing service.

Somewhere I found this code, and there is probably why the system is searching for **contao.image.image_sizes**

```
public static function getImageSizes()
    {
        @trigger_error('Using System::getImageSizes() has been deprecated and will no longer work in Contao 5.0. Use the contao.image.image_sizes service instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        return static::getContainer()->get('contao.image.image_sizes')->getAllOptions();
    }
```

Comment: `has been deprecated and will no longer work in Contao 5.0` - so why do you still use this function?

Comment: You got it wrong. I am not using that function. After the upgrade, it was left somewhere in system files or in files that came with extensions/plugins. I didn't manage to find any file where it was used, but still this error was triggered.

Comment: If **you** are not using that function, but any plugin or extension is: check which one, and then check whether it needs to be updated to be compatible with Contao 5

Comment: Yes, I managed to find the files that caused the problem and correct the code. Although the first solution I wrote above did the job as well. Thanks.

Comment: If this is not code you wrote on your own: editing any extension or plugin is not a good idea